# positive part of a random variable written as an integral

Tags: random-variable, integral

It is known that a random variable $X$ can be written in terms of positive and negative parts $X=X^+-X^-$.
Also, $X^+=\max(0,X)=\int_0^\infty \mathbb I(X>x)dx$.

Do you know how to show the equality $\max(0,X)=\int_0^\infty \mathbb I(X>x)dx$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a function of $x$, we have $f(x) \equiv I(X>x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in (-\infty, X)\\ 0 & x \in [X, \infty)\end{cases}$, so
if $X \ge 0$, then
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)  \, dx= \int_0^X 1 \, dx = X$$
and if $X < 0$, then
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)  \, dx= \int_0^\infty 0 \, dx = 0$$

Comment: $X^+=\max(0,X)=XI(X>0)=\int_0^{XI(X>0)}dx$. How to relate this with $X^+=\int_0^\infty I(X>x)dx$?

Comment: @CelineHarumi Sorry, fixed an error

Comment: I'm thinking in this line: $\int_0^{XI(X>0)}dx=\int_0^\infty I(XI(X>0)>x)dx$. But, as $x>0$, then $ I(XI(X>0)>x)=I(X>x)$ .

Comment: @CelineHarumi Doesn't my answer show that $\int_0^\infty I(X>x) \, dx =\begin{cases}X & X \ge 0 \\ 0 & X < 0 \end{cases}$?

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. You showed that $g(w)= \int_0^\infty I(X(w)\geq x)dx$ equals to $X(w)$ if $w\in\{X\geq 0\}$ and to $0$ if $w\in\{X<0\}$ which is the exact definition of $X^+$.